# how to migrate ftp route from xml to java

Tags: apache-camel

i began to refactor/ rebuild a xml based camel project to a java based one (i need to strictly separate configuration from functional stuff).
i am new to camel and so i am stumbling over the very first route, a ftp route. The ftp url and credentials are configuration but all the rest should be set in java.

at the moment the urie looks as follows:

```
ftp://<fromConfig>&amp;stepwise=true&amp;delay=1000&amp;move=${file:name}.trans&amp;recursive=true&amp;binary=true&amp;filter=#doneFilter&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=200&amp;eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=false&amp;sorter=#pcrfSorter
```

So how to do this in java. especially the stuff using beans with "#".

thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

The uri is the same in Java or XML DSL. Only that in XML mind you need to XML escape the `&` so it becomes `&amp;` etc.

The # is a lookup in the registry, see more here: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html

So the lookup happens in the Camel registry which can be a facade for JDNI / Spring etc. So it depends in what container you run Camel.

You can find a bit more details about Camel registry at: https://camel.apache.org/registry.html

Comment: i run it not in a container, it will run stand alone. I don't want to register a bean(pojo) in a xml to use it in java code. Is there a way to do all the routing config in java?
my problem with the documentation is that it sometimes only shows one side (xml or java) but i think this means not that is only possible in one way?!

Comment: If you run standalone read about the registry and use a simple registry to enlist your beans so the # lookup can find your beans.

Comment: Also see this example for running Camel standalone and binding beans to the registry: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. So it means the registry of classes keeps string based: i bind a string to a class and use the string in some other class (rout builder), instead of using the class directly.
Could you probably add the standalone link to your answer?